# resuming the same activity on button click

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I am  making an android app in which the user needs to add information. I want if the user left any blank field and clicks on the button the same activity in which other fields were filled should be started.

I am using intents for this and able to start the activity again but all the fields get emptied.
How can I do this with intent.

Thanks

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.register);


    Register=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.register);
    Reset=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.reset);

    firstName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstName);
    surName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.surname);
    email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.eMAil);
    password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passWord);
    retypePassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.retypePassword);
    town=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.town);
    cellno=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.cellno);
    dateOfBirth=(Button)findViewById(R.id.datepickerbutton);         
 Register.setOnClickListener(clickRegisterListener);

  private OnClickListener clickRegisterListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
         try{
                FirstName=firstName.getText().toString();
                SurName=surName.getText().toString();
                sex.setOnItemSelectedListener(new            MyOnItemSelectedListener());
                Email=email.getText().toString();
                Password=password.getText().toString();
                RetypePassword=retypePassword.getText().toString();
                Town=town.getText().toString();
                Cellno=cellno.getText().toString();

                if(FirstName.equals(""))
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
                    alertbox.setMessage("First Name field can not be left empty!");
                    alertbox.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                        {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, Register.class);
                       //   onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        }
                      });
                    alertbox.show();
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is pass all information that you want displayed to the activity with the intent. When you create your intent you "put extra" information in the intent.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
i.putExtra("variableName", "variable value");
```

Then in the activity you can retrieve the information:

```
Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras(); 
String var = extras.getString("variableName");
```

**Edit**:

If you want to save the activity state when it is is paused you need to save  the variables of interest in the onPause() method and then recover them in the onResume() method

Comment: through this code another activity would be started.. I dont want to start another activity instead I want to resume the same activity.

Comment: what do you mean resume the same activity? If the activity is already running its already running.

Comment: My actual problem is that if any of the field is left empty  I need to show an alert box which shows that particular field is empty on button click and thud the control should be back on the same activity with other fields having the fields filled as such.  Otherwise if all the fields are filled properly then the control should shift to another activity... now please tell me how to do that?? thanx

Comment: Why not use a Toast popup instead of an Alert dialog. What I don't understand is what is causing the activity to quit.

Comment: Its not clear at all from your description what is going on.  Let me take a stab at it. You have an activity (called A) with several entry fields and a button, when the button is clicked the you show a dialog if all the fields aren't filled out correctly.  Then you want to go back to A and keep all the fields populated?

Comment: When an activity, lets call it A, shows a Dialog. The onPause() method for A is called. When the dialog closes activity A resumes without needing to be called again and the onResume() method is called for A.  When onPause() is called you need to SAVE THE STATE you care about, then when onResume() is called you need to recover that state.

Comment: I am posting my code for this... can You tell me in detail about it??

Comment: @ekjyot, I don't really have the time to write up an example. Especially because there are dozens of examples on the web already, Do a google search for "Android onPause() onResume()" and read the android docs where there are also examples like this: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex3.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`startActivityForResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Comment: I am using startActivityForResult() method. but again all th fields get emptied on button click

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, Register.class);
          startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

Comment: your calling and called activities are same "Register". If you are updating values in the same activity then you don't need to do anything....just stop restarting the activity.........

Comment: within activity to update values if you are getting any problem use handler.....refer this tutorial:http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html